# How to get Discord member username from user id in python and move to another channel?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have got the list of user ids of all member from a voice channel

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '+'
@client.command()
async def move(ctx):
  voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="Meeting")
  memid= voice_channel.voice_states.keys()
  memlist=list(memid)
  for i in range(0, len(memlist))
    user = memlist[i]
    await user.move_to('Meeting-2')
```

I want to move all the users from one channel to another channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `user = await client.fetch_user(userid)` to get a user object from an id, however to move a user from one vc to another you need a member object. This can be done with `member = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(userid)` with guild being `guild = client.get_guild(server_id)` if you don't have ctx.